# SQL Query to check Attributes in same row which are not null

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with 6 attributes:

```
Att1   Att2   Att3   Att4   Att5   Total
Value  Null   Null   Null   Null    1
Null   Value  Null   Null   Null    1
Value  Value  Value  Value  Value   5
Null   Null   Value  Value  Value   3
```

What I want to do is to check in each row which attributes have value and update the 'Total' based upon how many values there are in each row. Like I've shown in the table above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
UPDATE TableName
  SET total = 
    CASE WHEN Att1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    + CASE WHEN Att2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END    
    + CASE WHEN Att3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    + CASE WHEN Att4 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    + CASE WHEN Att5 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: Was there another obvious way? +1 for a great answer

Comment: typo `TEEN` instead of `THEN`